# netcat in systemd service resets

Tags: systemd, netcat, nc

I am using netcat to connect to a server over TCP and continuously pipe the data received to file.

`nc 10.0.2.2 3456 > file.data`

When running this from terminal or a script it stays connected

I want to run this as a service to keep it running and restart on failure. But when running the same script in a systemd service it quickly disconnects and the log says

`ncat: connection reset by peer`

Is there any limitations to running nc as a service?

I have it set up something like:

```
[Unit]
User=user
Type=simple
ExecStart=ncscript.sh
Restart=always
```

Answer (score 0):

I reliably run `nc` as a service. This is what I do:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/nc 10.10.1.20 19184
StandardOutput=journal
StandardError=journal
```

In my case, I use `nc` to trigger a remote socket unit which triggers a remote service.  The stdout of that service is routed via the socket, and directly into my journal.

You are doing some redirection in your script (`> file.txt`). That's the only difference I see, and so I assume it is the cause of your problem.   Instead, you could use:

```
StandardOutput=append:/path/to/file.txt
```

---

It's possible we don't have the full story.  If you do something like this:

```
nc 10.0.2.2 3456 > file.data &
```

That can cause other issues when the bash script ends.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason nc sends a FIN when running via systemd wich makes the server RST the connection.

Solved by adding `--recv-only` to `nc`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).